# 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "target" argument must be an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received null' : React Testing library using msw

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, msw

When I run a test code using React testing library with MSW, I got an error

```
buffer.js:210
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('target', ['Buffer', 'Uint8Array'], target);
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "target" argument must be an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received null
at _copy (buffer.js:210:11)
at Buffer.copy (buffer.js:768:12)
at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr/XMLHttpRequest-impl.js:864:11)
at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Gunzip.<anonymous> (/Users/.../node_modules/request/request.js:1073:12)
at Gunzip.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
at Gunzip.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
at Gunzip.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:152:32) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

There are 6 test functions in a `Component.test.tsx` file and all functions have similar code like

```
test('some test..', async () => {
  server.use(
    rest.get('/api/1/..', (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(ctx.json({...}));
    }),

    rest.get('/api/2/..', (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(ctx.json({...}));
    }),
  );

  render(<Component />);
  await waitFor(() => screen.getByText(/test test/i));

});
```

above.

The bigger problem is sometimes the test passes, even though most time it fails.

I tried dividing each test function in a different test file, like `component1.test.tsx`, `component2.test.tsx`, ... `component6.test.tsx`.

And the result was really weird because Jest pass whole files.

I really want to know why the error is happening.

Comment: I encountered this before, BUT the reason was that I was running the tests on Github Actions, and I have a method that fetches the content on Github

Comment: I have been seeing this issue intermittently as well. Have you made any progress? How are you able to tell which test is causing the issue?